2019: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
  -- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Chinese Language over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          7
Users destroyed³                                  1          0
Users contacted                                   1          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue            97         51
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                3          1
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue        243         78
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue              130         34
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue               624        103
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue              164         50
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Questions unprotected                             0          1
Questions reopened                                3          0
Questions protected                               1          4
Questions migrated                                2          0
Questions flagged⁵                               10        207
Questions closed                                 80          3
Question flags handled⁵                         100        117
Posts unlocked                                    0         12
Posts undeleted                                  11         13
Posts locked                                     10         38
Posts deleted⁶                                   66        194
Posts bumped                                      0        200
Comments undeleted                                1          0
Comments flagged                                  0        351
Comments deleted⁷                               191        565
Comment flags handled                           141        210
Answers flagged                                  10        301
Answer flags handled                            291         20
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Chinese Language without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).   
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: 2018: a year in moderation...
You can also check out this report on other sites
Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites

Wishing you all a happy new year...

I'll compare these numbers with 2018: a year in moderation, and to the language-based SE sites which have comparable size to Chinese.SE: German.SE, French.SE, Spanish.SE, and Russian.SE (as per the November snapshot).
Observations:

We have far fewer total Community¹ reviews (317) than German.SE (5363), French.SE (1959), and Spanish.SE (2488), and Russian.SE (783).  [I omit the full details.]
Far fewer posts are deleted than German.SE, French.SE, Spanish.SE, and Russian.SE.
Practically no questions in 2019 were closed without a diamond moderator involved.
We delete fewer posts than our counterparts (on par with Russian.SE, which is about half the size).
We delete far fewer comments than our counterparts, and fewer than last year.
There was a significant drop in edit reviews since last year.


Numbers...
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           113        274 [2018]
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue            97         51 [2019] <----

I have no explanation for this significant drop in edit reviews.
Questions closed                                 87         16 [2018]
Questions closed                                 80          3 [2019] <----

Questions closed                                 46        419 [German 2019]
Questions closed                                113         72 [French 2019]
Questions closed                                 51        100 [Spanish 2019]
Questions closed                                133          3 [Russian 2019]

I'm not sure what to make of this, but I don't think it's good if diamond moderators are required to close questions.  Perhaps we have diamond moderators who are also active participants.
Posts deleted⁵                                  122        162 [2018]
Posts deleted⁶                                   66        194 [2019] <----

Posts deleted⁶                                  168        647 [German 2019]
Posts deleted⁶                                  188        351 [French 2019]
Posts deleted⁶                                  216        242 [Spanish 2019]
Posts deleted⁶                                   84        156 [Russian 2019]

We're not deleting as much as our counterparts.  Probably a lot of the Community post deletions are automatic question deletions, but we tend to answer everything which prevents automatic question.  We also seem very hesitant to downvote.
Comments deleted⁶                               229        625 [2018]
Comments deleted⁷                               191        565 [2019] <----

Comments deleted⁷                             1,301      1,678 [German 2019]
Comments deleted⁷                             1,252      2,427 [French 2019]
Comments deleted⁷                               603      2,105 [Spanish 2019]
Comments deleted⁷                               687        594 [Russian 2019]

Wow.  We're massively different than other sites.  I guess we're not chatterboxes.

Addendum: Quoting from 2019: a year in closing on meta.SE:
                Site                   Asked   AskedAndClosed PctAskedAndClosed AllClosed DuplicatesClosed DuplicatesReopened OTClosed OTReopened UnclearClosed UnclearReopened TooBroadClosed TooBroadReopened OpinionBasedClosed OpinionBasedReopened
------------------------------------ --------- -------------- ----------------- --------- ---------------- ------------------ -------- ---------- ------------- --------------- -------------- ---------------- ------------------ --------------------

German Language                          1,968            454           23.07 %       465               89                  4      261         28            64              13             35                1                 16                    2
French Language                          1,731            183           10.57 %       185               70                  2       62          4            19               4             22                1                 12                    1
Chinese Language <----                   1,238             79            6.38 %        83               17                  1       59          0             7               2              0                0                  0                    0
Spanish Language                         1,109            146           13.17 %       151               66                  2       60          6            15               0              7                0                  3                    0
Russian Language                           607            133           21.91 %       136               13                  1       89          8            22               7             11                2                  1                    0


Searching for created:2019 closed:true, we get 39 hits (some questions would be deleted and would not be found).  Below I list the diamond-hammer closure distance (at which position the diamond hammer was used to close the question):

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 (23%)
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 (49%; cumulative 72%)
1, 2, 3, 4 (10%; cumulative 82%)
1, 2, 3, 4 (10%; cumulative 92%)
1 (3%; cumulative 95%)
N/A: 1, 2 (5%; cumulative 100%)

That's far worse than I thought.  This seems to be because (a) we don't have that many questions that require closing [after adding the new data "2019: a year in closing"], and (b) we have diamond moderators who are also active participants.
